# Caching / Mapping strategy for standalone java application

Tags: java, caching, hashmap, memcached, ehcache

I have a SQL Table with disk size ~50 GB. The table is read-only and thus, ideal for caching. For faster and frequent look ups, what would be ideal -

1. Java 8 Hash Map.
2. Memcached.
3. Hibernate EH Cache.
   or anything better ?

(provided 200 GB of main memory is available for JVM).

Comment: The structure of the data, access patterns, operational and application constraints, and performance concerns all influence the decision. Simply putting all the data on-heap may be problematic due to GC pause times and a slow server startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start trying [Guava cache](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained)  (Google Core Libraries for Java 1.6+)

> Generally, the Guava caching utilities are applicable whenever:
>
> - You are willing to spend some memory to improve speed.
> - You expect that keys will sometimes get queried more than once.
> - Your cache will not need to store more data than what would fit in    RAM. (Guava caches are local to a single run of your application.
>     They do not store data in files, or on outside servers.
>
>   If this does not fit your needs, consider a tool like Memcached.)

Comment: Memcached for a standalone application looks like too much io operation, since it is a externally managed application. Guava Cache, can be used locally in an application. Thanks.

Comment: Network I/O is cheap, multi-gets mask much of it, and has predictable latencies. The local caches are often poorly suited for large sizes (GC pause times) and high concurrency ([benchmarks](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Benchmarks)).

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work for Terracotta on Ehcache

Another option would be to use the upcoming [Ehcache 3](https://ehcache.github.io) with its offheap tier. This would allow you to cache the whole table in RAM but outside of the control of the GC, thus not being a source of pause times.